# Input will not fade away when I click the radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a html css js code. in one part of it I have a one group of radio buttons (including 2 items). I want this to happen: if I click the first radio,  textbox1 appears, if I click the second one, textbox1 disappears and textbox2 appears and vice versa.

this scenario is happening when I click on one of them, but it is not working when I click the second one.

this is my html code:

```
<label>Which one do you want to enter?</label>
<br/>
<label>Budget:</label>
<input name = "submethod" id = "submethodbudget"  type="radio" value = "bud"/>
<div id = "smethod" style="display:none">
   <input type="text" name = "budgetsub">
</div>
<label>Number of Clicks per Month:</label>
<input name = "submethod" id= "submethodclicks" type="radio" value = "clckno"/> 
<div id = "smethod2" style="display:none">
   <input type="text" name = "clicksnosub">
</div>
<br/>
```

and this is my js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#submethodbudget").click(function() {
        $("#smethod").show("300");
        $('#smethod').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'bud') ? 'block':'none');
   });
   $("#submethodbudget").click(function() {
        $("#smethod2").hide("300"); 
   });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#submethodclicks").click(function() {
        $("#smethod2").show("300");
        $('#smethod2').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'clckno') ? 'block':'none');
   });
   $("#submethodclicks").click(function() {
        $("smethod").hide("300"); 
   });
</script>
```

can you tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
$("smethod").hide("300");
```

to :

```
$("#smethod").hide("300");
```

I edit your code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Which one do you want to enter?</label>
        <br/>
        <label>Budget:</label><input name = "submethod" id = "submethodbudget"  type="radio" value = "bud"/>
        <div id = "smethod" style="display:none">
            <input type="text" name = "budgetsub">
        </div>
         <label>Number of Clicks per Month:</label><input name = "submethod" id= "submethodclicks" type="radio" value = "clckno"/> 
         <div id = "smethod2" style="display:none">
              <input type="text" name = "clicksnosub">
          </div>
        <br>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>
             $("#submethodbudget").click(function() {
                 $("#smethod").show("300");
                 $('#smethod').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'bud') ? 'block':'none');
                 $("#smethod2").hide("300"); 
             });

             $("#submethodclicks").click(function() {
                 $("#smethod2").show("300");
                 $('#smethod2').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'clckno') ? 'block':'none');
                 $("#smethod").hide("300"); 
             });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submethodbudget").click(function(){
        $("#smethod").show(200);
                $("#smethod2").hide(200);
    });
    $("#submethodclicks").click(function(){
        $("#smethod2").show(200);
        $("#smethod").hide(200);
    });
});
```

You can even try this using jquery - css method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct ! I have some smart code for that ,have a try it.

```
 $("input[name=submethod]").click(function() {        
        $('div').hide("300");
        $(this).next("div").show("300");        
   });
```